# ReactJS [issue on production] - TypeError: (void 0) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image: ']

I'm facing the above error on production build, not even getting the issue reference...
your help will really be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Note - on local, it works fine - development mode, but the same code won't work on a production.

**React js version is - 16.12.0, and webpack version - 4.41.6**

Comment: what happens, if you downgrade the versions?

Comment: Are you using any global scripts in your code? Once I had that same issue and I had to access my global scripts from the `window` object.

Comment: @JuniusL. yes tried with react 16.8.19 but still getting same error

Comment: @DANIELSSEJJEMBA yes used window object will check  by removing it.

Comment: I noticed the production build is strict so it can produce some errors but when you run your build script you should be able to trace the build error...

Comment: did you found something ? have something similar but when I added a new module material-ui/lab

Comment: This issue is because of react fabric ui version updated, got resolve by updating latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Facing this issue when trying to import something that is not exported from a module. I'm sure this is the case only for **PRODUCTION** build, not for development.

Probably, this error is only applicable for **Webpack 4** and has been fixed in Webpack 5.

In my case:

`index.js` of a module:

```
export {
  foo,
} from './utils';
```

Your file:

```
import * as Utils from 'utils';

Utils.bar(); // bar is not exported!
```

Production bundle contains: `(void 0)() // crashes!`

Development bundle contains user friendly comment:

```
/* Cannot get final name for export "bar" in 
   "./node_modules/utils/index.js" (known exports: foo) */

undefined();
```

and fails silently ‍♂️

Comment: I was using `js-cookie` library, and had `import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'` which caused the same issue. Using `import Cookies from 'js-cookie'` worked, thx

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working with team and we don't have git ignore for ios project so the core files doesn't belong to the same compiler , i managed to resolve this issue by first deleting ios folder (if you use pod copy podfile)

then 
react-native upgrade --legacy true
copy your pod file again to the new ios folder
cd ios pod install cd -
open your project in xcode and build 
select schema to release then build again

Don't forget to have [git ignore](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/.gitignore) as follow